# cosmos Point Read

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

My cosmos db query

```sql
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE c.id = "1437156155"
AND c.npi = 1437156155
```

npi is partition key

It is consuming 2.83 RUS

how to perform Point read so that it consume 1RU

sample document

```json
    {
        "npi": 1518966761,
        "Entity_Type_Code": "NA",
        "Employer Identification Number (EIN)": "NA",
        "Provider Last Name (Legal Name)": "NA",
        "Provider_First_Name": "NA",
        "Last Update Date": "NA",
        "NPI_Deactivation_Reason_Code": "NA",
        "NPI_Deactivation_Date": "03/20/2006",
        "NPI_Reactivation_Date": "NA",
        "Healthcare_Provider_Taxonomy_Group_1": "NA",
        "id": "1518966761"
    }
```

I have to achieve this in python

index policy

```json
    {
        "indexingMode": "consistent",
        "automatic": true,
        "includedPaths": [
            {
                "path": "/*"
            }
        ],
        "excludedPaths": [
            {
                "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Anything need to perform in index policy? I found below link it has example for dotnet, i am looking for python

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/point-reads-versus-queries/

Comment: 1RU is based on the assumption that the document size is 1K.

Comment: document size is less than 1KB and update sample doc, @Sajeetharan

Comment: The doc size is kind-of a red herring here; the issue is that 1) the OP needs to do a *point read* vs a *query* and 2) there's no specific programming question.

Comment: @sagar - you can look up all the details on doing point-reads (read up on `read_item()`), which is not the same as performing a SQL SELECT query (which will cost more than 1 RU)

Answer (score 2):

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/samples-python

```
response = container.read_item(item="1437156155", partition_key="1437156155")
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking at the RUs consumed on the Data Explorer, Point operations need to be executed through the SDKs themselves, a query that filters by id and partition key is still considered a query.

Read using [Python SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos/samples/document_management.py#L50) as Matias mentioned above,

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.